# Angularjs: Why doesn't the parameter in a custom directive is undefined when bind in template?

Tags: angularjs, binding, scope, directive

Here is my test code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("myWidget", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        submitText: "@"
    },
    template: "<button>{{submitText}}</button>",
    link: function(scope) {
        if(scope.submitText == null){
            scope.submitText = 'Button';
        }    
    }
 };
});
```

html:

```
<my-widget></my-widget>
<br>
<my-widget submit-text="TEST"></my-widget>
```

and, here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/2cAYt/9/

I want to define submitText as the label of the button in my-widget. It should have a default value in case it is not gave a specific one. But it seems not working to giving a default value. Please, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting issue - the problem seems to be that angular's digest cycles eventually settle `scope.submitText` back to undefined. Here is my theory for what happens:

- You set `scope.submitText = 'Button'`
- Since @ is a two-way data binding, angular tries to bind the new value `'Button'` back to the expression in your attribute
- In your first case, there's no expression, so it tries to bind `'Button'` to some *undefined expression*, essentially doing nothing
- As an aside, even if you tried to set `scope.submitText` in the second case(where you specified `submit-text="TEST"`), you would get the same result, this time trying to bind `'Button'` to a *static expression*
- On the next digest, the *undefined expression* still has a value of `undefined`, so angular binds `scope.submitText` back to `undefined`

One possible solution would be to remove the attribute binding altogether, e.g.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("myWidget", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
    },
    template: "<button>{{submitText}}</button>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.submitText = attrs.submitText || 'Button'
    }
  };
});
```

If needed, you could still use an *interpolation* - `<my-widget submit-text="{{interpolation}}"/>` when your submit-text isn't static.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However,'@' is not two-way data binding. '=' is.

Comment: I got an explanation from my friend. check out the link  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1525